# Spring JDBC query for count of a specific field

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I would like to know how I would get the count of a specific column within my database. Each distinct value in my column I would like to store the returned column value and its count within a Java List. This is what I have so far:

```
public List<Sighting> getCountPest() {
    return jdbc.query("select pest_name, count(pest_name) from sighting group by pest_name", new RowMapper<Sighting>() {
                 public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        Sighting sighting = new Sighting();
                        sighting.setCount(rs.getInt("count")); // will not work as  no column name in table
                        sighting.setPest_name(rs.getString("pest_name"));
                        return sighting;
                    }      
               });
}
```

Essentially I would like to use pest_name and returned count value for a chart.
This is my sightingRowMapper if it helps:

```
public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(rs.getString("username")); // setting the username if logged in

    Sighting sighting = new Sighting();
    sighting.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    sighting.setTotal_pests(rs.getInt("total_pests"));
    sighting.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
    sighting.setInformation(rs.getString("information"));
    sighting.setPest_name(rs.getString("pest_name"));
    sighting.setPark(rs.getString("park"));
    sighting.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
    sighting.set_Username(rs.getString("username"));
    sighting.setUser(user);

    return sighting;
}
```

Comment: Is query working well from db console? How your mapper looks?

Comment: @Admit Updated with RowMapper.

Comment: @Admit query works well from my SQL workbench. Gives expected results. I just want to store these results and display them in a Pie chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sighting I guess you would need another result mapper than, which will deal only with `pest_name` and `count` column. At least it would be cleaner.

If you don't like creating new class for that, you could create anonymous class :

```
jdbc.query(
   "select pest_name, count(pest_name) from sighting group by pest_name",
   new RowMapper<Sighting>() {
     public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return sighting;
        }      
   });
```

Or use existing, but changing the query a bit:

```
select pest_name, count(pest_name) as total_pests
```

but it's a hack :)

Comment: I will try creating an Anonymous class first. But what do I put between "new RowMapper<Sighting>(){...here...});"?

Comment: Does count have to be an attribute in the Sighting class?

Comment: Updated. There goes method implementation, you should create and fill with data Sighting object.

Comment: Ok I will try this and see how I go.

Comment: I have updated my POST. Is that query correct? now? I had to make a 'count' attribute in my Sighting class.

Comment: Seems so, you just need to try it out.

Comment: It doesnt work. The query itself fails. Gives me bad SQL grammar.

Comment: it feels column name in mysql would be `count(pest_name)`, so rewrite query as `SELECT ..., count(pest_name) as count ...`

Comment: Ok I got something. The query seems to be working and grouping the pest_name together. But for some reason, I cannot get the count as "sighting.setCount(rs.getInt("count"));", the column 'count' does not exist in the table. So I some how need to get the count value into a variable or somehting.

Comment: All done. I just got the value of the count and then set it int he RowMapper. Thank you for your help.